# While trying to run react-native run-android, JS bundler is closed immediately

Tags: react-native

I want to use react-native on windows 10 which is newly installed.
I followed all instructions on https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started (React Native CLI Quickstart).

But when I use `npx react-native run-android` the `JS server` closed immediately!

How can I solve it?

My system info:

```
    OS: Windows 10 10.0.18363
    CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4810MQ CPU @ 2.80GHz
    Memory: 9.97 GB / 15.88 GB
  Binaries:
    Node: 13.3.0 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE
    Yarn: 1.21.1 - C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin\yarn.CMD
    npm: 6.13.4 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD
  SDKs:
    Android SDK:
      API Levels: 19, 23, 26, 27, 28, 29
      Build Tools: 23.0.1, 26.0.3, 27.0.3, 28.0.3, 29.0.2
      System Images: android-28 | Intel x86 Atom, android-28 | Intel x86 Atom_64, android-28 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom, android-28 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64, android-28 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom, android-28 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom_64, android-29 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: Version  3.5.0.0 AI-191.8026.42.35.6010548
  npmPackages:
    react: 16.9.0 => 16.9.0
    react-native: 0.61.5 => 0.61.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed `Android Studio`? Also, are you using the Expo version or Pure React Native version? One last thing is can you try to run this command; `npm start` or `expo start`?

Comment: Yes, I installed `Android Studio` and using the Pru React native. `npm start` not working

Comment: Can you share the reproducible example? I would like to help you for investigation.

Comment: After searching a lot, ] noticed that Node JS 13.3 has a problem with RN and causes many problems to solve this issue, I downgraded Node JS to 12.8. Thanks for your time